# Law of reversibility of light and total internal reflection

Tags: optics

When a light passes from a denser to a rarer medium at critical angle of incidence the light rays graces through the surface of the denser medium.According to the law of reversibility of light same thing should happen when we reverse the direction of light.But, how can that be? How does the light know when to go into the denser medium?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does light reflect if incident at exactly the critical angle?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52555/)

Comment: The link I've posted is an exact duplicate of your question though you can be forgiven for not finding it as the title of the question isn't helpful.

Comment: There is NO law of reversibility of "light".    In geometrical optics, which is a simplified mathematical model, the direction of rays is reversible, but in real physical world propagation of electromagnetic wave energy, there is no reversibility except in the trivial case of propagation in a single homogeneous medium.   If any boundary, between media is involved, there is no reversibility.   Fresnel reflection describes the ray splitting into reflected and transmitted beams.   Reverse those two and you do not get one beam; you get a new fourth beam as well.

Comment: Time-reversal symmetry still holds over a boundary between media (though not if the media are lossy.) In the general case you would get four beams, yes, but if you reverse the reflected and transmitted beams and they come together again _with the appropriate relative phase difference_ that they had in the forward case, then they will destructively interfere in the pathway of the fourth beam, and all the energy ends up in the original beam.

Comment: That requires coherent light and also requires total optical paths less than the coherence length.  The OP made no mention of coherent light.